# Friction question. Need an advice :)

Tags: iphone, box2d

I have a moving player in a Box2d world and a moving platform which is in the box2d world too.

Now i my player jumps on the top of the platform my player is not moving with the platform if the platform is moving. I tried to set a friction on the player and on the platform (`friction`: 1.0f) but now if they have a contact either moves and it stops. if my player moves the platform moves into that direction (the player direction).

I thought ..... i could set the player friction to 0.5f and the platform to 1.0f........

what should i do??? should i change something in the `density, restitution`?? or only the `friction`??

In which value(s) should i change it??

Help please.

Thank you very much :D

PS: I'm using Objective C + iphone sdk + cocos2d

Edit: code

```
//player
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
//platform
    fixtureDef.density = .0f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
```

Comment: You might find some existing answers to your question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com (but don't cross-post this there)

Comment: I found nothing there :[. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's got something to do with the way the platform is being moved. Is enough force being applied once the player is on top of the platform? Because the mass of the player might be to high for the platform to move...just suggesting.